# see get min value of nodes, exceptional case

Tags: c, struct, module, nodes, c99

Given the following struct:

```
typedef struct node_t {
    int x;
    struct node_t *next;
} *Node;
```

**Please Note: the definition above is given to me as is and can't be changed.**

I wrote the following function:

```
inline int getMin(Node *list1,Node *list2)
{
    int first_value=INT_MAX,second_value=INT_MAX;
    if (*list1)
    {
        first_value=(*list1)->x;
    }
    if (*list2)
    {
        second_value=(*list2)->x;
    }
    if (first_value<second_value)
    {
        *list1=(*list1)->next;
        return first_value;
    }
    *list2=(*list2)->next;
    return second_value;
}
```

It receives 2 pointers to a series of Nodes while each node has two attributes: `x` and `next` (a pointer to the next code)

My code should get the minimum value when comparing the values of the current two nodes, while it works fine with 99% of the cases it doesn't work with the case where `list1` points to a node that its value is `INT_MAX` and `next` points to `null` and `list2` is `NULL`
how can I fix this?

I fixed this by changing the following code:
`if (first_value<second_value)` to
`if (first_value<=second_value)`
but I have a new problem:
`list2` points to a node that its value is `INT_MAX` and `next` points to `null` and `list1` is `NULL`

---

**Edit: Here is the last version of my code:**

helper functions:

```
int advance(Node *node) {
    int node_value = (*node)->x;
    *node = (*node)->next;
    return node_value;
}

int getMin(Node *list1, Node *list2) {
    assert(*list1 || *list2);
    if (!(*list1)) {
        return advance(list2);
    }
    if (!(*list2)) {
        return advance(list1);
    }
    if ((*list1)->x < (*list2)->x) {
        return advance(list1);
    }
    return advance(list2);
}
```

main function:

```
ErrorCode mergeSortedLists(Node list1, Node list2, Node *merged_out) {
    if (!merged_out) {
        return NULL_ARGUMENT;
    }
    if (!list1 || !list2) {
        return EMPTY_LIST;
    }
    if (!isListSorted(list1) || !isListSorted(list2)) {
        return UNSORTED_LIST;
    }
    Node ptr = *merged_out;
    int total_len = getListLength(list1) + getListLength(list2);
    for (int i = 0; i < total_len; i++) {
        int min = getMin(&list1, &list2);
        if (i != 0) {
            ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
            if (!ptr->next) {
                destroyList(*merged_out);
                return MEMORY_ERROR;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->x = min;
    }
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is the classical merge sort code where you have four cases provided that not both lists are exhausted: (1) a is exhausted; (2) b is exhausted; (3) a < b and (4) the rest, that is a ≥ b. You have tried to express the firs two by means of the last two, but because your lists can have `INT_MAX` as value, that solution isn't robust. Write out these cases explicitly. (There's also the question what happens when both nodes are null. Is that controlled from outside?)

Comment: yes when they are both null is totally checked, can you kindly help writing or improving my code?

Comment: @yano but I need to advance the original pointer

Comment: @clark_smith It is unclear what is the purpose of the function. What is it doing?! For example what is this statement *list1=(*list1)->next; doing?

Comment: you guys are right, my apologies, will delete

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am using this as a helper function to merge two sorted nodes, so after I get the minimum value I want the current node to point to the next on in the same "body" since I used its value.

Comment: Note: "receives is not quite 2 pointers to a series of Nodes while each node has two attributes:" is not quite right.  The function receives 2 pointers to `Node`.  `Node` itself is a pointer to a `struct node_t`.  More like the function receives 2 pointers to pointers to nodes.

Comment: OT:  hiding a pointer via a typedef is a very poor programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classical merge sort code where you have four cases provided that not both lists are exhausted:

1. *a* is exhausted;
2. *b* is exhausted;
3. *a* < *b* and
4. *a* ≥ *b*.

You have tried to coalesce the two first cases where one of the nodes is null with the comparison, but because your lists can have `INT_MAX` as value, that solution isn't robust.

Write out these cases explicitly. First a little auxiliary function that advances a node and returns the value:

```
static int advance(Node *nd)
{
    int res = (*nd)->x;

    *nd = (*nd)->next;

    return res;
}
```

Now your actual function is very simple:

```
int getMin(Node *list1, Node *list2)
{
    assert(*list1 || *list2);

    if (*list1 == NULL) return advance(list2);
    if (*list2 == NULL) return advance(list1);
    if ((*list1)->x < (*list2)->x) return advance(list1);

    return advance(list2);
}
```

See it in action [on ideone](https://ideone.com/JcqkPg).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but since my getMin is inlined (since I use it a lot) should I inline advance() too?

Comment: Perhaps, don't know. Unless you are going to mergesort millions of elements it's not going to matter a lot, I guess. (And I imagine that just redesigning the algorithm so that it reconnects the nodes straight away will give better speed benefits.)

Comment: I tried to inline getMin() but now I am getting an error: static function 'advance' is used in an inline function with external linkage [-Werror,-Wstatic-in-inline]

Comment: Yes. `static` functions aren't visible to the outside, so they can't be called by inlined code. Don't inline or inline both, but don't make them static, whatever.

Comment: if I inline both I still get error (even if I remove static)

Comment: Then don't inline your function. The `inline` keyword means that the function must be visible to other modules. Do you want that? I doubt it, because your function is an auxiliary function to yor megre sort, therefore it needs to be known only to mergesort. I suggest another strategy: Make all functions (except the mergesort function) `static`. The compiler can then inline it as it sees fit.

Comment: (You can read this as: Stop obsessing about inlining. You probably don't need the optimization benefits. I'll go out on a lib here and say that there will be much more potential for optimization in the way your mergesor is implemented.)

Comment: regarding: `assert(*list1 || *list2);`   this `assert()` will trigger when either of the two dereferenced values is NULL, so will never (in those cases) reach the following code.  Do you want your code to crash when either of the lists reaches its' last node

Comment: @user3629249: This `assert` will not crash when one of the two lists reaches its last node, because `Node` is a pointer type and the `list1` and `list2` are pointers to pointers. That's not my syntax and I'm neither happy with the `Node` type or with this auxiliary function for merge sort, but it is in line with what OP uses. The `assert` is mainly there to document the OP's assertion (in a comment) that the function is never called when both node pointers are `NULL`.

Comment: (I thought I put it there to avoid comments about my code not catching that case. Now I have to defend that `assert`. Well, never mind. The code will crash, of course, when the caller doesn't provide valid pointers to node pointers, but let's not assume that. Or let's throw in some more `assert`s)

Comment: @MOehm could you kindly elaborate how to make my algorithm faster?

Comment: @MOehm my whole and latest code in now available in my recent edit of the post (at the bottom)

Comment: I will comment only briefly, because I've already spent a lot of time on this question. In general, the structure of the code feels wrong: Apparently you pass in the first node of the resulting list. What happens if both lists are empty?

Comment: As for optimization: You create a copy of the two lists. Do you need that? The algorithm could be faster and straightforward if you just rearranged the existing nodes. (The array mergesort works in-place, even if it uses an auxiliary array.) Next, you should not determine the lengths of the lists. You don't need to know the length of the list, you only need to know whether you are at the end. (That's similar to `while (i < strlen(s))` vs. `while (s[i])`, where the first is O(N), the second O(1).)

Comment: That said, for merge sort, you must split the array in two at some time, so you'll have to walk the whole list anyway. in each iteration. When you want to optimize code for  linked lists, you must take advantage of things that linked lists are good for (removing, inserting elements, concatenating lists) and try to avoid things that linked lists are not good at (get their length, access random elements).

Comment: Okay, since I've already spent a lot of time on this, here's my implementation [on ideone](https://ideone.com/zrocpS).

Comment: Thanks but you didn't notice that next and x are hidden so I can't access them from main